# Crontab Scheduling Issue

Tags: unix, cron, scheduled-tasks

My crontab entry is like below:

```
30 1 9-29 * 1-6 test.sh
```

I want my cronjob to run at 1:30 AM GMT on dates from 9 to 29 from Monday to Saturday. However, my script (test.sh) is being executed on Sundays also.

I gave the range `1-6` (meaning 1 for Monday and 6 for Saturday).
Can someone tell me where am I wrong or what can be done so that the script does not run on Sundays?

Comment: From the manpage: Note: The day of a command's execution can be specified in the following two fields — 'day of month', and 'day of week'.  If both fields are restricted (i.e., do not contain the "*" character), the command will be run when either field matches the current time.  For example "30 4 1,15 * 5" would cause a command to be run at 4:30 am on the 1st and 15th of each month, plus every Friday...... I think your script should test which day of the week it is running on.

Comment: Hi Bib, Thanks a lot for your valuable reply. Really Insightful for me. So, you mean to say, we should check the day of the week in the script. Can you kindly let me know, how to do that? Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: Look at the manpage for date....   date +%u, or even date +%w.